# Graphviz from sklearn cannot find my file?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

So i'm trying to build a decisiontree in python using sklearn.

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier, export_graphviz
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import graphviz

cancer = load_breast_cancer()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(cancer.data, cancer.target,
                                                    stratify=cancer.target, random_state=42)
tree = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0, max_depth=4)
tree.fit(X_train, y_train)

export_graphviz(tree, out_file=r"C:\Users\obaro\OneDrive\Documents\tree.dot", class_names=["malignant", "benign"],
               feature_names=cancer.feature_names, impurity=False, filled=True)

with open(r"C:\Users\obaro\OneDrive\Documents\tree.dot") as f:
    dot_graph = f.read()
    display(graphviz.Source(dot_graph))
```

When I try to run this code in Jupyter, though, I get a FileNotFound error and an ExecutableNotFound error. At first, I tried using a relative path, but that didn't work, so I tried using an absolute path. The file WAS created and is in my current home directory so I'm not sure what's going on here. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You mean you successfully run `export_graphviz` *from Jupyter*, and then with `open` in the same notebook you get a `FileNotFound` error?

Comment: yeah, exactly. Any idea what could be happening?

Comment: In the same notebook and the same session? `export_viz` works OK and produces the file, and `open` in the very next cell cannot find it? you sure?

Comment: Yeah. It's so frustrating

Comment: Doesn't make sense. Try saving with `export_graphviz` in a different filename `tree1.dot`, and confirm that the file is indeed created - maybe there is a prexisting `tree.dot` file in your home folder.